# In ASP.NET MVC 2 / EF, comma in number causes model binding error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

In my HTTP POST controller method for add/editing data, I'm receiving an entity from my EF data model.  Some of the fields in that entity are of type double.  Everything works fine unless the user types in a comma for a thousands separator, which then causes a model binding validation error.

Has anyone run into this before?  Is replacing the default model binder with a custom one the only solution or is there a better approach?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modelbinding for MVC uses a culture invariant mode of binding. Therefore numbers must be in the `100000.00` format.

Though the following relates to the datetime it also is pertinent to the decimal type as well.

Quote from the asp.net team member:

"*This is intentional. Anything that is part of the URI (note the 'Uniform' in URI) is interpreted as if it were coming from the invariant culture. This is so that a user in the U.S. who copies a link and sends it over IM to a friend in the U.K. can be confident that his friend will see the exact same page (as opposed to an HTTP 500 due to a DateTime conversion error, for example). **In general, dates passed in RouteData or QueryString should be in the format yyyy-mm-dd so as to be unambiguous across cultures**.*

*If you need to interpret a QueryString or RouteData parameter in a culture-aware manner, pull it in as a string, then convert it to the desired type manually, passing in the desired culture. (DateTime.Parse has overloads that allow you to specify a culture.) If you do this, I recommend also taking the desired culture as a QueryString or a RouteData parameter so that the 'Uniform' part of URI isn't lost, e.g. the URL will look something like ...?culture=fr-fr&date=01-10-1990.*"